# Assigning using dereference operator causing infinite loop

Tags: c++, arrays, csv, pointers, strtok

I am trying to parse a character array  using the `strtok()` function into a pointer array.  I initialize my character array and pointer array:

```
char micPointsChar[30 + 1] = {};
float* micPoints[8][8] = {};
void initMicPoints(char* micPointsChar);
```

I call the function `initMicPoints()` and pass the character array `micPointsChar[40]` to it:

```
int main()
{
  char micPointsChar[40] = "1,1.546466,2.543\n2,3.343,4.432\n";
  initMicPoints(micPointsChar);
  return 0;
}
```

Then I loop through each line in the .csv file extracting the data in each cell by using the delimiters "," and "\n".

```
void initMicPoints(char* micPointsChar)
{
  static int i = 1;
  static int micNum = 1;
  static int numMics = 2;
  static float coordinateDec = 0;

  char *coordinate = strtok(micPointsChar, ",\n");
  coordinateDec = atof(coordinate);
  while (micNum <= numMics)
  {
    Serial.print("looping number of mics\n");  //debugging
    while (i <= ((micNum * 3)) && (coordinate != NULL))
    {
      if (i == ((micNum * 3) - 2))
      {
        *micPoints[micNum][0] = coordinateDec;
        Serial.print("*micPoints[micNum][0] = "); //debugging
        Serial.print(*micPoints[micNum][0]);
        Serial.print("\n");
      }
      else if (i == ((micNum * 3) - 1))
      {
        *micPoints[micNum][1] = coordinateDec;
        Serial.print("*micPoints[micNum][1] = "); //debugging
        Serial.print(*micPoints[micNum][1]);
        Serial.print("\n");
      }
      else if (i == ((micNum * 3) - 0))
      {
        *micPoints[micNum][2] = coordinateDec;
        Serial.print("*micPoints[micNum][2] = "); //debugging
        Serial.print(*micPoints[micNum][2]);
        Serial.print("\n");
      }
      coordinate = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
      coordinateDec = atof(coordinate);
      i++;
    }
    micNum++;
  }
}
```

The code compiled fine.  When I run the code there is an infinite loop with the following output:

```
looping number of mics
*micPoints[micNum][0] = 1.00
        oping number of mics
*micPoints[micNum][0] = 1.00
        oping number of mics
...
```

This does not occur when I just assign the float `coordinateDec` to a float array `foo[i]`:

```
  if (i == ((micNum * 3) - 2))
  {
    foo[i] = coordinateDec;
    Serial.print(foo[i]);
    Serial.print("\n");
  }
  else if (i == ((micNum * 3) - 1))
  {
    foo[i] = coordinateDec;
    Serial.print(foo[i]);
    Serial.print("\n");
  }
  else if (i == ((micNum * 3) - 0))
  {
    foo[i] = coordinateDec;
    Serial.print(foo[i]);
    Serial.print("\n");
  }
```

I obtain a correct output of:

```
looping number of mics
1.00
1.55
2.54
looping number of mics
2.00
3.34
4.43
```

Why does assigning via the dereference operator send the program into an infinite loop?

Comment: `char micPointsChar[40] = {"1,1.546466,2.543\n2,3.343,4.432\n"}` does not make sense--you're putting an array of one string into an array of 40 char.  Remove the curly brackets.

Comment: You're declaring `micPoints` as an array of `float *` but you're not initializing those pointers in the code shown.  Is that not shown or is that part of the problem?